# static array on functions.php

Tags: php, functions

In functions.php, I want to access the DB once to get an ACF object, and then "save" it locally to prevent further requests to the DB.

I thought of first calling the following function in the "init' hook.

Then, supposedly, when I call it on later hooks the $current_store var is already set because of the use of the "static" keyword, and the function will stop on the first "if" - returning the already saved static var.

It doesn't work - when accessing the function on later hooks 'isset($current_store)' returns false.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function get_current_store()
{
    if (isset($current_store)) {
        return $current_store;
    }

    $store_url_parts = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    $store_subdomain = $store_url_parts[0];

    $store_url_parts_reversed = array_reverse($store_url_parts);

    if (in_array("il", $store_url_parts_reversed)) {
        $domain = $store_url_parts_reversed[2];
    } else {
        $domain = $store_url_parts_reversed[2];
    }

    if ($store_subdomain == $domain) {
        $current_store = 'main';

        return $current_store;
    }

    if ($stores_page = get_page_by_title('Stores', OBJECT, 'option')) {
        $stores_page_id = $stores_page->ID;

        if (function_exists('have_rows')) {
            if (have_rows('stores', $stores_page_id)) {
                $store_url_parts = get_store_url_parts();
                $store_subdomain = $store_url_parts[0];
                $stores          = array();

                while (have_rows('stores', $stores_page_id)) {
                    the_row();

                $store = get_row(true);

                    $stores[] = $store;
                }

                $subdomains = array_column($stores, 'store_subdomain');

                $current_store_id     = array_search($store_subdomain, $subdomains);

                static $current_store = array();

                if ($current_store_id !== false) {
                    $current_store = $stores[$current_store_id];
                } else {
                    $current_store = false;
                }

                return $current_store;
            }
        }
   }
```

}

Comment: When you say "later on", do you mean later on the same page load, or on other requests or other pages?

Comment: Same page load. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for the [Object Cache](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache):

> WP_Object_Cache is WordPress' class for caching data which may be
>   computationally expensive to regenerate, such as the result of complex
>   database queries.

You can store things in the cache with `wp_cache_set()` and retrieve them with `wp_cache_get()`. You just need to give it a key and value, as well as a group name unique to your theme/plugin or set of functionality to avoid conflicts:

```
function get_current_store()
{
    // Check if the current store is cached.
    $cache = wp_cache_get( 'current_store', 'my_plugin' );

    // If it is, return the cached store.
    if ( $cache ) {
        return $cache;
    }

    // Otherwise do the work to figure out $current_store;

    // Then cache it.
    wp_cache_set( 'current_store', $current_store, 'my_plugin' );

    return $current_store;
}
```

Now no matter how many times you run `get_current_store()` on a page it will only do the work of generating the current store variable once.

Comment: Thanks! I did some reading and it seems to be the case, but I want to make sure as it is very important for us - there is no chance a certain user gets a cached object from another user's session, is this correct? (Because if there is a chance it is very bad for us). Will the 'wp_cache_add_non_persistent_groups' is a good addition to make sure it isn't happening? Is there something else recommended to do for securing this? Thanks again.

Comment: The object cache isn't persistent at all by default, but there are plugins that can make it persistent. If you want to future-proof against one of those plugins in case you want to use one later, then yes, using `wp_cache_add_non_persistent_groups( 'my_plugin' )` is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Jacob Peattie answer is a great alternative.

But if someone iterested, the problem with my original code is that `static $current_store` needs to be declared at the beggining of the function.

This code works:

```
function get_current_store()
{
    static $current_store;

    if (isset($current_store)) {
        return $current_store;
    } else {
        $store_url_parts = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        $store_subdomain = $store_url_parts[0];

        $store_url_parts_reversed = array_reverse($store_url_parts);

        if (in_array("il", $store_url_parts_reversed)) {
            $domain = $store_url_parts_reversed[2];
        } else {
            $domain = $store_url_parts_reversed[2];
        }

        if ($store_subdomain == $domain) {
            $current_store = 'main';

            return $current_store;
        }

        if ($stores_page = get_page_by_title('Stores', OBJECT, 'option')) {
            $stores_page_id = $stores_page->ID;

            if (function_exists('have_rows')) {
                if (have_rows('stores', $stores_page_id)) {
                    $store_url_parts = get_store_url_parts();
                    $store_subdomain = $store_url_parts[0];
                    $stores          = array();

                    while (have_rows('stores', $stores_page_id)) {
                        the_row();

                        $store = get_row(true);

                        $stores[] = $store;
                    }

                    $subdomains = array_column($stores, 'store_subdomain');

                    $current_store_id = array_search($store_subdomain, $subdomains);

                    $current_store = array();

                    if ($current_store_id !== false) {
                        $current_store = $stores[$current_store_id];
                    } else {
                        $current_store = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return $current_store;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if the $current_store is some kind of global variable then your function should start with

```
function get_current_store() {
    global $current_store
    // the rest of your source code here ...
```